# AngularJS testing callbacks to then functions within services

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, promise, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm looking to write a Jasmine unit test which executes a callback function passed to a then function. This then function is chained to a call to the AngularJS $http service, and it's inside a custom service. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
app.service('myService', function($rootScope, $http) {
  var service = this;

  var url = 'http://api.example.com/api/v1/resources';

  service.resources = {
    current: []
  };

  service.insertResource = function (resource) {
    return $http.post(url, resource).then(function(response){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('resources:updated', service.resources.current);
      return response;
    });
  };
});
```

Here's my attempt to write a test which executes this callback, but to no avail:

```
describe('resource service', function() {

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myapp'));

  var resourceService;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_resourceService_) {
    resourceService = _resourceService_;
  }));

  it('should insert resources', function() {
    resourceService.insertResource({});
  });
});
```

Comment: Would you mind to explain what the actual problem and the resulting question is? "It does not work!" and "Can you make it work?" won't be accepted ;) And please add it to your question by using the edit button, don't use comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you could take:

- Use $httpBackend.expectPOST
- Use $httpBackend.whenPOST
- Move the code in the callback to a named function (not an anonymous one) and write a test for this function. I sometimes take this route b/c I don't want the trouble of writing tests with `$httpBackend`. I only test the callback function, **I don't test that my service is calling the callback**. If you can live w/that it's much simpler approach.

Check the documentation for [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) for details. Here's a simple example:

```
describe('resource service', function() {

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myapp'));

  var resourceService, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    resourceService = $injector.get('resourceService');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    // tests will fail if expected HTTP requests are not made
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequests();
    // tests will fail if any unexpected HTTP requests are made
    $httpBackened.verifyNoOutstandingExpectations();
  });

  it('should insert resources', function() {
    var data: { foo: 1 }; // whatever you are posting
    // make an assertion that you expect this POST to happen
    // the response can be an object or even a numeric HTTP status code (or both)
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://api.example.com/api/v1/resources', data).respond({});
    // trigger the POST
    resourceService.insertResource({});
    // This causes $httpBackend to trigger the success/failure callback
    // It's how you workaround the asynchronous nature of HTTP requests
    // in a synchronous way
    $httpBackend.flush(); 
    // now do something to confirm the resource was inserted by the callback
  });
});
```